# PhpGrid(jQuery) and Mootools together

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mootools

I have a problem with using [phpGrid](http://phpgrid.com/) with Mootools library. I have tried the [following example](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) with no success. The problem is, that phpGrid prints out from somewhere the following syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/phpGrid/css/start/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/phpGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="/phpGrid/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/phpGrid/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/phpGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/phpGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/phpGrid/js/grid.import.fix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lastSel;jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var grid_ws3600 = jQuery("#ws3600").jqGrid({......
```

That is why I am unable to include:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

before var lastSel. I have tried scanning files *.js files with Grep to see If I could found that javascript code that is generated there, but with no luck.

For displaying phpGrid table I use what is defined in the docs:

```
$dg -> display();
```

My Mootools code:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() { myCal1 = new  Calendar({ Date1: 'Y-m-d' },{days: ['Nedelja', 'Ponedeljek', 'Torek', 'Sreda', 'Četrtek', 'Petek', 'Sobota'], 
months: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'Marec', 'April', 'Maj', 'Junij', 'Julij', 'Avgust', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'], direction: -1}); });
window.addEvent('domready', function() { myCal2 = new Calendar2({ Date2: 'Y-m-d' },{classes: ['calendar'], days: ['Nedelja', 'Ponedeljek', 'Torek', 'Sreda', 'Četrtek', 'Petek', 'Sobota'], 
months: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'Marec', 'April', 'Maj', 'Junij', 'Julij', 'Avgust', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'], direction: -1}); });
</script>
```

Comment: since this is a commercial product i doubt the source code is available for you to look at in plain text. as for noConflict -> they seem to use jQuery instead of $ anyway, so all you need to do to make your mootools work is load it AFTER jquery comes in. mootools since 1.2.1 (?) will NOT overwrite $ if it belongs to another library / defined elsewhere, it falls back to `document.id` instead. also, when you talk of 'no success', exactly what is the problem you are getting? data grid works and mootools stuff fails or the reverse?

Comment: With no success I mean that data grid works and mootools does not. The problem with your solution (to include mootools after jquery) is, that I have a calendar which uses mootools, that users can use to select timeline. So calendar has to be loaded BEFORE the jQuery stuff. You really think it would not be possible to somehow inlude jQuery.noConflict()? Because it's just one line that needs to be put in to work.

Comment: then change mootools references to `$()` to `document.id()` instead or use a closure to assign it: `(function($) { ... mootools funcs })(document.id)`

Comment: I have added my mootools code in my question. Tried to pass $ to function and add document.id at the end but still would not show up. Could you please take a look at the code and answear as a post the correct code to work. It's just I am not very familiar with mootools and jQuery just yet, just happened to found that cool claendar: http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/calendar/, that works and looks very good.

Comment: this is a mootools 1.11 class. mootools 1.11 can't drop to document.id so jquery.noconflict is your only route

Comment: Okay, that's not good:(. So basically I will not be able to solve this, because all that generated code (updated again my first post, forgot that it also generates src for jQuery files, which is the main reason that I cannot add before loading Mootools library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a great idea to use two (relatively) large frameworks that do very similar things simultaneously.  You're adding overhead like crazy, which will ultimately slow your application down.

I have a (garbage legacy) app that has to run both Jquery and Prototype and it's working fine if I just replace all the $ with jQuery (it is case specific, at least in my application)  I've seen the noConflict listed all over the web, but it's working just fine without it for me.  Again, as soon as it's feasible to un-do the Prototype mess and convert it over to Jquery, I'll be doing that....but our shop has been overwhelmed with work for some time now, so I haven't had the chance.

As an aside, I'm a huge fan of [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and would recommend you take a look at it--I've used it hundreds of times in apps and clients LOVE it.  I'm also a big fan of Jquery UI, which includes a wonderful calendar app and is already available to you via your UI include.  Jquery UI will have it's own grid released in the next 6-12 months, which will mean even less overhead for script downloads.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this great answear. I agree the DataTables look very good and they are free. jQuery datepicker is also something I have not meet before. Nice to know such things exist. I think my problem just disappeared with this new options:).